# jenkins Ant compile error cannot find symbol when deploy war/ear to container 'tomcat7'

Tags: java, jenkins, ant

```
error:
  [mkdir] Created dir: /root/.jenkins/jobs/eauto100-dev-auto/workspace/javamall/WebContent/WEB-INF/build/classes/shop
    [javac] Compiling 801 source files to /root/.jenkins/jobs/eauto100-dev-auto/workspace/javamall/WebContent/WEB-INF/build/classes/shop
    [javac] /root/.jenkins/jobs/eauto100-dev-auto/workspace/javamall/shop/com/enation/app/shop/core/action/api/OrderBackApiAction.java:312: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         String orderTime = DateUtil.getNowTime();
    [javac]                                    ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method getNowTime()
    [javac]   location: class DateUtil
    [javac] /root/.jenkins/jobs/eauto100-dev-auto/workspace/javamall/shop/com/enation/app/shop/core/action/api/OrderBackApiAction.java:330: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         String open_id = member.getOpen_id();
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method getOpen_id()
    [javac]   location: variable member of type Member
    [javac] /root/.jenkins/jobs/eauto100-dev-auto/workspace/javamall/shop/com/enation/app/shop/core/action/api/OrderBackApiAction.java:340: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         String orderTime = DateUtil.getNowTime();
    [javac]                                    ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method getNowTime()
    [javac]   location: class DateUtil
    [javac] /root/.jenkins/jobs/eauto100-dev-auto/workspace/javamall/shop/com/enation/app/shop/core/action/backend/MemberAction.java:367: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             oldMember.setIs_repairer(member.getIs_repairer());
    [javac]                                            ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method getIs_repairer()
    [javac]   location: variable member of type Member
    [javac] /root/.jenkins/jobs/eauto100-dev-auto/workspace/javamall/shop/com/enation/app/shop/core/action/backend/MemberAction.java:368: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             oldMember.setAtt_time(member.getAtt_time());
    [javac]                                         ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method getAtt_time()
    [javac]   location: variable member of type Member
    [javac] /root/.jenkins/jobs/eauto100-dev-auto/workspace/javamall/shop/com/enation/app/shop/core/action/backend/MemberAction.java:369: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             oldMember.setUnion_id(member.getUnion_id());
    [javac]                                         ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method getUnion_id()
    [javac]   location: variable member of type Member
    [javac] /root/.jenkins/jobs/eauto100-dev-auto/workspace/javamall/shop/com/enation/app/shop/core/action/backend/MemberAction.java:370: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             oldMember.setOpen_id(member.getOpen_id());
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method getOpen_id()
    [javac]   location: variable member of type Member
    [javac] /root/.jenkins/jobs/eauto100-dev-auto/workspace/javamall/shop/com/enation/app/shop/core/action/backend/MemberAction.java:371: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             oldMember.setInvite_pwd(member.getInvite_pwd());
    [javac]                                           ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method getInvite_pwd()
    [javac]   location: variable member of type Member
    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 8 errors
```

---

> additions:

thoese methods are exists,and this project is a ordinary java project not maven

Comment: Seems like classpath related problem. You need to ensure the classpath entries are correct and available

Comment: This looks like a project build problem, not a deployment to tomcat issue. As stated above your ANT build has a problem with its compile classpath, without showing code can't help further.

Answer (score 0):

Finally,I remove the jenkins item ,and new same item with original configuration. It works. OMG! It must be a bug of jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem arose when I copied the jenkins item and didn't properly initialized the values specially under ant(advance) you should properly populate BuildFile name and its properties.